# Importing integers instead of characters with R

Tags: r

I'm importing a dataset of numbers. Just one column being **Numbers_Picked** which has 600,000 rows. Each row consist of **20 integers** ranging from 01 to 80, each **separated by a white space**. My problem is R will only handle it as characters. When represented as characters, all 20 numbers show up.

```
library(readr)
numbers_picked <- read_delim("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/csv/numbers_picked.csv", 
    " ", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(numbers_picked = 
col_character()))
View(numbers_picked)
```

When I use the white space delimiter and set it to integer, the data preview show that the column only takes one value.

```
  library(readr)
  numbers_picked <- read_delim("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/csv/numbers_picked.csv", 
      " ", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(numbers_picked = 
  col_integer()))
  View(numbers_picked)
```

Basically, I want to represent 20 integers in one column.

here is a sample of the dataset

```
numbers_picked
06 18 20 21 24 32 36 40 44 47 50 52 55 57 60 61 62 68 72 79
03 05 12 13 14 16 17 18 24 28 33 34 35 39 44 55 62 63 64 67
09 10 12 13 15 25 30 31 36 42 43 44 46 48 51 57 65 69 75 79
08 12 15 20 27 33 34 37 41 43 44 45 54 55 60 61 66 70 72 76
```

Windows 10

RSTUDIOS - Latest

File - .csv
Link -[Large File 600,000 + lines](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0_E0L0RjSfpU1FLYnNGLUhsYUU)

Comment: Maybe use another separator? E.g.: `sep = ';'`. That should place everything in one column.

Comment: To me it's not entirely clear what you want to do. What exactly do you mean by "I want to represent 20 integers in one column"? The following gives me an integer column for each of the 20 columns: test <- read.table("test.csv")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention was to get a data frame with a single list-column of integer vectors, then you can do the following.

Read in the column as a character vector, then `str_split` it into a list of character vectors. We can then `map` each of the character vectors to an integer vector.

```
library('tidyverse')

csv_text <- 'numbers_picked
06 18 20 21 24 32 36 40 44 47 50 52 55 57 60 61 62 68 72 79
03 05 12 13 14 16 17 18 24 28 33 34 35 39 44 55 62 63 64 67
09 10 12 13 15 25 30 31 36 42 43 44 46 48 51 57 65 69 75 79
08 12 15 20 27 33 34 37 41 43 44 45 54 55 60 61 66 70 72 76'

read_csv(csv_text) %>%
  mutate(numbers_picked = stringr::str_split(numbers_picked, ' ') %>% map(as.integer))
#   numbers_picked
#           <list>
# 1     <int [20]>
# 2     <int [20]>
# 3     <int [20]>
# 4     <int [20]>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a .csv file with the numbers you provided using ' ' as a separator and this worked like a charm.

```
numbers_picked <- read.table("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/csv/numbers_picked.csv",
sep = " ")
```

Comment: This gives me the error:            Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 20 elements

Comment: When I give put the header = TRUE, i get the following:   read.table("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/csv/numbers_picked.csv", header = TRUE,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: Can you put your csv file in some sort of cloud (Dropbox, Drive) and provide us with the link? Because it seems to have some quirks

Comment: The link is at the bottom of the original post